# acces data in firebase with angular 4

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I have acces to data in firebase when I use angular 4 ... 
in rules firebase i modify that to:

> {
>     "rules": {
>       ".read": true,
>       ".write": true
>     }
>   }

but also error I d'ont show data Firebase and I have this result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTueo.png)

code service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
    import { FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
    import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
    import { Employee } from '../Employee';

    @Injectable()
    export class EmployeeService {

    employees:AngularFireList<any[]>;
    Employee:FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

      constructor(public af:AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.employees = this.af.list('/employeesdb') ;
       }

       getEmployees(){
        return this.employees;
       }

    }
```

code components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { EmployeeService } from '../../services/employee.service';
    import { Employee } from '../../Employee';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-employees',
      templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
    })
    export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
    employees: Employee[];

      constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService) { 

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        /*this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(employees => {
            this.employees = employees;
        });*/
        console.log(this.employeeService.getEmployees());

      }

    }
```

Comment: what are you expecting, and what is the error?

Comment: @alphapilgrim error is data is not show my friend :(

Comment: try `this.employees = this.af.list('/employeesdb').valueChanges();`

Comment: @alphapilgrim ... I have this error with your edit of my code : ERROR in C:/xampp/htdocs/employeesang4/src/app/services/employee.service.ts (15,4): Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<any[]>'.
  Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>'.

Comment: any help please

Comment: [angularfire2-docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/v3.md#inject-angularfire-and-bind-it-to-list), try `Employee: Observable<any[]>;` instead